# Apache Flink - Using class with generic type parameter

Tags: java, generics, java-8, apache-flink

How can I use a class with generic types in flink? I run into the error:

> The return type of function 'main(StreamingJob.java:63)' could not be determined automatically, due to type erasure. You can give type information hints by using the returns(...) method on the result of the transformation call, or by letting your function implement the 'ResultTypeQueryable' interface.

The class I use is of the form:

```
class MaybeProcessable<T> {
    private final T value;

    public MaybeProcessable(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T get() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And I am using a example flink job like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    env.addSource(new PubSubSource(PROJECT_ID, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME))
        .map(MaybeProcessable::new)
        .map(MaybeProcessable::get)
        .writeAsText("/tmp/flink-output", FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE);

    // execute program
    env.execute("Flink Streaming Java API Skeleton");
}
```

Now I can add a TypeInformation instance using the `.returns()` function:

```
.map(MaybeProcessable::new).returns(new MyCustomTypeInformationClass(String.class))
```

But this would require me writing my own serializer. Is there not an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you make a non-generic subclass: `class StringX extends MaybeProcessable<String>`?

Comment: Good one, for some functions I could do this. But in other cases I would like to reuse Map functions and thus not make them work on StringX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 
`.returns(TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<MaybeProcessing<#CONCRETE_TYPE_HERE>>{})` for each re-use of a generically typed MapFunction to set the return type without creating any more custom classes of your own.